# Restrict current logged in user in SPClientPeoplePicker control

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I am using custom SPClientPeoplePicker control in my page. its working fine and accepting all users from current site.

Can we restrict current logged in user in people picker control ?

I am using like below

```
 function initializePeoplePicker1() {
            var schema = {};
            schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
            schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
            schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
            schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
            schema['Width'] = '100%';
            for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper('txtpicker' + i, null, schema);
            }
        }
```

Example:- If "ABC" is current user then i want to restrict "ABC" in people picker control. Can we achieve that using SPClientPeoplePicker ?

Comment: when you say restrict, do you mean other user values are not allowed to the people picker or exclude current user from people picker?

Comment: Hi Abdul, Yes if am current user then in people picker , not allowed me to put my name.

Comment: Added a solution using Custom form validation. Check it out. As far as i know there aren't any OOTB way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

We can use [_spPageContextInfo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx) to get the current user name.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loginName = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
</script>
```

Then, get value from the people picker control (SPClientPeoplePicker control). Compare the values with the current user information to see if the current user is in the people picker. If it exists, remove it from people picker using DeleteProcessedUser function.

Demos (also work on SPO):

[SharePoint Client People Picker Control Helper](https://platinumdogs.me/2016/04/08/sharepoint-client-people-picker-control-helper/)

[SharePoint 2013: Client Side People Picker](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.sg/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-client-side-people.html)

Comment: OP wants to restrict the current user from being setup in people picker field.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `PreSaveAction` to write your custom validation to check if a people picker field contains current user.

```
function PreSaveAction(){

    var currentUserName= _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;

    // FOR SINGLE USER PEOPLE PICKER FIELD
    var peoplePickerFieldValue= SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('PeoplePickerInternalName').GetValue()[0].DisplayText;

    if(currentUserName == peoplePickerFieldValue)
    {
        console.log('Field can`t contain current User');
        alert('Field can`t contain current User');
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('Validation passes');
        return true;
    }

    //// FOR MULTIPLE USER PEOPLE PICKER FIELD
    //var validationStatus=true;

    //$(SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('PeoplePickerInternalName').GetValue()).each(function(){
    //
    //  if(currentUserName == this.DisplayText){
    //      
    //      console.log('Field can`t contain current User');
    //      alert('Field can`t contain current User');
    //      validationStatus=false;
    //  }
    //});
    //
    //if(validationStatus==false){
    //      console.log('Field can`t contain current User');
    //      alert('Field can`t contain current User');
    //      return false;
    //}
    //else 
    //{
    //  alert('Validation passes');
    //  return true;
    //}

}
```

Here it compares the display name of the current user with the people picker display value and if there is a match, `PreSaveAction` returns `false` which fails validation and prevents the item from being saved.

You can modify the code to compare Email fields also.

Add the above script as CEWP in your Newform.aspx or EditForm.aspx depending on where you want it.

**Dependencies:**

jQuery, [SPUtility](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/tree/master/WikiFiles/docs)